# Get filenames for all files in a chrome extension directory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a chrome extension which will add custom images to a webpage. I want the users to put all their images in the "backgrounds" folder, and I want my extension to be able to retrieve the file names of every file in the "backgrounds" directory in the extensions folder. It seems like there is no way to do this in chrome extensions. When I try to use the chrome fileSystem API, I get this error:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'fileSystem' is only allowed for packaged apps, but this is a extension.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This comment thread may be useful: https://github.com/Wykks/Untamed-Now-Playing-Next/issues/40

Comment: @daniel I learned nothing from this and am actually more confused now.

Comment: Basically you can only use fileSystem with Chrome apps, not extensions. It talks about separating aspects of the extension/app into different things but yeah..

Answer (score 7):

You can get read-only access to your extension's folder with [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry), with which you can work using the [HTML5 FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

However, **this will not allow you to do what you want to do.**

While you're developing an extension, it will work fine, as Chrome does not mind changes to the extension's folder - they are expected.

However, when the extension is deployed to users, Chrome will maintain a cryptographic hash of the extension folder's contents. In case there are any external modification to the files, the extension is considered compromised and is forcibly disabled.

So you should consider other approaches instead, such as:

- using the above HTML5 FileSystem API to have a virtual persistent filesystem to which you can let the user "upload" files through your UI;
- storing data as `blob:`/`data:` URIs in `chrome.storage` or IndexedDB;
- asking the user to put the files in a cloud drive your extension can access using its usual API.

Comment: `getPackageDirectoryEntry` is not available in service workers (background). I wanted to create a dynamic extension, where I define an interface `ServiceWorkerBase` and dynamic load modules from the chrome extension folder that implements that interface.

Comment: It's a *very* legacy API, I'm not surprised it didn't make the jump to SW.